# Unable to print tokens in game board

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a simple board game. What I want to do when the program runs first print the empty board, then asks the user for `X` and `Y` coordinates and then prints the board with the player token in the coordinates he entered. When I run the program it prints the empty board and then asks me for the `X` coordinate and then the `Y` coordinate, then it gives me the following error:

> X: 1, Y: 2
>
> Y: 2, Y: 3
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What is making that error and how do I fix it? Thank You

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct p1Data{
    int xCoordinate;
    int yCoordinate;
    bool flag;
};

char **gameBoard;
int height, width, boardArea, xCor, yCor, dataSize, i;

char **allocateMemory(int boardHeight, int boardWidth);
void fillBoard(char **board, int height, int width, struct p1Data data[], int sizeData);
void printBoard(char **board, int boardHeight, int boardWidth);
void freeBoardArray(char **board, int boardHeight);

int main(int argc, char** argv ){
    height = 4;
    width = 4;

    boardArea = height * width;

    struct p1Data data[boardArea];

    dataSize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);

    data[0].flag = false;
    gameBoard = allocateMemory(height, width);
    fillBoard(gameBoard, height, width, data, dataSize);
    printBoard(gameBoard, height, width);
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < boardArea; i++ ){
        printf("Enter X-Coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &xCor);
        printf("Enter Y-Coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &yCor);

        data[i].flag = true;
        data[i].xCoordinate = xCor;
        data[i].yCoordinate = yCor;

        fillBoard(gameBoard, height, width, data, dataSize);
        printBoard(gameBoard, height, width);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

char **allocateMemory(int boardHeight, int boardWidth){
    int i;
    char **gameBoard;

    gameBoard = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*boardHeight);

    for( i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++ ){
        gameBoard[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*boardWidth);
    }

    return gameBoard;
}

void fillBoard(char** board, int height, int width, struct p1Data data[], int sizeData){
    int i, j, x, y;

    for(i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++ ){
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    
    if(data[0].flag == true ){
        for( i = 0; i < sizeData; i++ ){
            x = data[i].xCoordinate;
            y = data[i].yCoordinate;
            
            board[x][y] = 'O';
            printf("X: %d, Y: %d\n", x, y);
        }
    }
}
void printBoard(char **board, int boardHeight, int boardWidth){
    int i, j;

    printf("/");

    for( i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++ ){
        printf("-");
    }

    printf("\\");

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++ ){
            printf("|");
        for(j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++ ){
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
       
        printf("|");
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\\");
    
    for( i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++ ){
        printf("-");
    }
    
    printf("/");
}

void freeBoardArray(char **board, int boardHeight){
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++ )
        free(board[i]);
    free(board);
}
```

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code causes the compiler to output several warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   Just to get you started, the parameters: `argc` and `argv` are not used.  so the code should be using the following signature for main: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (data[0].flag == true) {
    for (i = 0; i < sizeData; i++) {
        x = data[i].xCoordinate; //<== not intialized
        y = data[i].yCoordinate; //<== not intialized

        board[x][y] = 'O'; //<= x/y are undefined
        printf("X: %d, Y: %d\n", x, y);
    }
}
```

You have to initialize `data[i].xCoordinate` and `data[i].yCoordinate` otherwise these values are undefined. Later you call `board[x][y]` which causes the error.

```
//initialize here:
for (i = 0; i < boardArea; i++) 
{
    data[i].flag = false;
    data[i].xCoordinate = 0;
    data[i].yCoordinate = 0;
}
fillBoard(gameBoard, height, width, data, dataSize);
...
```

In this case you can also initialize using `memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));` to set initial values to zero.

Note, you can also simplify your game by avoiding a 2-D array. Knowing X/Y coordinate and Width/Height, you can calculate the index as `x + y * width`. Or use division and mod operator `%` to extract X/Y coordinate from 1-D array index. Example:

```
void printBoard(char *data, int w, int h)
{
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
            printf("%c", data[x + y * w] ? 'O' : '.');
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int width = 4;
    int height = 4;
    int area = width * height;
    int i, xCor, yCor;
    char data[area];
    memset(data, 0, area);
    for (i = 0; i < area; i++)
    {
        printBoard(data, width, height);
        printf("Enter X-Coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &xCor);
        printf("Enter Y-Coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &yCor);

        int index = xCor + yCor * width;
        if (index < area)
            data[index] = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```